# Errors pushing to bare repository on separate Windows 7 computer

Tags: git, ssh-keys

I'm trying to set up Git in our office which is a 100% Windows environment with a handful of developers. I've found an unused Windows 7 computer running in our closet that I was able to install Git on and set up a bare repository so that I can push to/fetch from it from my Windows 7 work laptop. I've cloned the repository to my laptop successfully, but when I try to push any changes I get the following error:

```
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects[K
remote: fatal: failed to write object[K
error: failed to push some refs to '//remote-computer-name/some/dirs/here/repository'
```

After some googling, I've found many references to setting up SSH keys for GitHub or other services (which I'm not using), and I'm not sure how to do that within my current setup on another Windows 7 computer where my bare repository exists. Any suggestions? Beginner here. Thanks!

Comment: On your own box inside your cloned repo, please type: `git remote -v` and post the result here. From that we'll be able to find out what protocol you were using for cloning.

Comment: origin  //computer-name/c/sites/www.site.com/htdocs/applications/registration (fetch)
origin  //computer-name/c/sites/www.site.com/htdocs/applications/registration (push)

Comment: Does that help you at all? Some more information: my dev workspace is a Windows 7 laptop with the latest version of Git. The bare repo I've cloned from is on a Windows 7 desktop in my office and on the same network, also running the latest version of Git. Because I saw the 'permission' message, I tried making the repo a Windows shared folder (right-click > Properties > Sharing > Advanced > Share this folder, Permissions set to Full for everyone), but still no luck. This seems like it would be much easier if I had a Linux box laying around, but I don't.

Comment: OK. So the remote uses Samba protocol (shared folders). Shared folders in Windows have 2 layers of permissions: Those defined in the files/folders Security tab, and those defined in the Sharing tab. Please make sure that both allow full read/write access for you in the shared folder.

Comment: Thank you. Still no luck, even after giving 'Full Control' access to my account in every panel I could find, both for the folder and subfolders/files. If the problem is definitely with Windows permissions I'll bug our network administrator to see if she has any ideas.

Comment: In my local git config file I changed "url = //computer-name/some/dirs/here/repository-name" to "url = file://computer-name/some/dirs/here/repository-name" and I think that works! Will continue testing. Any issues doing it this way (does that change the protocol)?